# Windows Authentication Issue going from Edge to Edge Chromium

Tags: c#, iis, webforms, windows-authentication

**The problem**

I have a web forms application that is a management application to monitor other applications on the network. Currently this is used in edge or internet explorer, but we will be using edge chromium in the near future.

It is using windows authentication at the moment and works ok on edge and internet explorer, however there is an edge in edge chromium.

When run the application everything is fine, but when i go to a new page i get prompted to enter my windows credentials. When i do this it does not work and simply asks again.

[Enter Windows Credentials](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4tewC.png)

Below is the authorization area of my web config.

```
  <authorization>
    <remove users="*" roles="" verbs="" />
    <add accessType="Allow" users="" roles="Sample group inserted here" />
  </authorization>
```

If i hit cancel then i receive a 401. Below are the response and request headers. I did check these on IE as well and when it is trying to load this template it fails twice then succeeds on the third attempt.

[Headers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R7ukv.png)

I have tried adjusting the authorization area and look at it on all browsers.

**Expected result**

I would expect once i run the application my identity is recognised and i can go to any area without being prompted.

Here is my complete web config

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=169433
  -->
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="" value="https://localhost:44386" />
    <add key="webpages:Version" value="2.0.0.0" />
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
    <add key="PreserveLoginUrl" value="true" />
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="OracleUser" value="" />
    <add key="OraclePassword" value="" />
  </appSettings>
  <!--
    For a description of web.config changes see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=235367.

    The following attributes can be set on the <httpRuntime> tag.
      <system.Web>
        <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.7.1" />
      </system.Web>
  -->
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.7.1" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
    <pages>
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Helpers" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Optimization" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.WebPages" />
      </namespaces>
    </pages>
    <machineKey decryptionKey="Left out on purpose" validationKey="Left out on purpose" />
    <identity impersonate="true" />
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
    
    <security>
      <authorization>
        <remove users="*" roles="" verbs="" />
        <add accessType="Allow" users="" roles="Left out on purpose" />
      </authorization>
    </security>
  <handlers>
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
      <remove name="OPTIONSVerbHandler" />
      <remove name="TRACEVerbHandler" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="*" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
    </handlers></system.webServer>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Helpers" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-2.0.0.0" newVersion="2.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-4.0.0.0" newVersion="4.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-2.0.0.0" newVersion="2.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="WebGrease" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.6.5135.21930" newVersion="1.6.5135.21930" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Oracle.DataAccess" publicKeyToken="89b483f429c47342" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.112.3.0" newVersion="4.112.3.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-10.0.0.0" newVersion="10.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Http" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.2.3.0" newVersion="5.2.3.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Http.WebHost" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.2.3.0" newVersion="5.2.3.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Net.Http.Formatting" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.2.3.0" newVersion="5.2.3.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework" />
  </entityFramework>
</configuration>
```

Successful request IE
[IE 200](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HBBPv.png)

First 401 IE

[First 401 IE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OeBcz.png)

Second 401 IE

[Second 401](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IN5uo.png)

I managed to find a solution (working locally in visual studio). I moved the authorization second to system.web and changed it to this. However this still only works in IE when i deploy to iis.

```html
 <authorization>
      <allow roles="" />
      <deny users="*" />
    </authorization>
```

from this

```html
  <security>
      <authorization>
        <remove users="*" roles="" verbs="" />
        <add accessType="Allow" users="" roles="" />
      </authorization>
    </security>
```

I would appreciate some information on this. I am not a web forms developer.

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=169433
  -->
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="" value="https://localhost:44386" />
    <add key="webpages:Version" value="2.0.0.0" />
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
    <add key="PreserveLoginUrl" value="true" />
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="OracleUser" value="" />
    <add key="OraclePassword" value="" />
  </appSettings>
  <!--
    For a description of web.config changes see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=235367.

    The following attributes can be set on the <httpRuntime> tag.
      <system.Web>
        <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.7.1" />
      </system.Web>
  -->
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.7.1" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
    <pages>
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Helpers" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Optimization" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.WebPages" />
      </namespaces>
    </pages>
    <machineKey decryptionKey="" validationKey="" />
    <identity impersonate="false" />
    <authorization>
      <allow roles="Removed deliberately" />
      <deny users="*" />
    </authorization>
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
  <handlers>
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
      <remove name="OPTIONSVerbHandler" />
      <remove name="TRACEVerbHandler" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="*" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
    </handlers></system.webServer>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Helpers" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-2.0.0.0" newVersion="2.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-4.0.0.0" newVersion="4.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-2.0.0.0" newVersion="2.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="WebGrease" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.6.5135.21930" newVersion="1.6.5135.21930" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Oracle.DataAccess" publicKeyToken="89b483f429c47342" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.112.3.0" newVersion="4.112.3.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-10.0.0.0" newVersion="10.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Http" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.2.3.0" newVersion="5.2.3.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Http.WebHost" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.2.3.0" newVersion="5.2.3.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Net.Http.Formatting" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.2.3.0" newVersion="5.2.3.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework" />
  </entityFramework>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the syntax is wrong? Try

```
<authorization>
        <deny users="*" />
        <allow roles="role" />
</authorization>
```

Comment: attempted but this is not the issue

Comment: `<deny users=*>` will unconditionally deny everyone, no matter if they are authenticated or not.

Comment: it will yes, but surely if you allow the role, then users in that role are granted access

Comment: why does it work locally using visual studio but not when i deploy to IIS?

Answer (score 0):

First, make sure you enabled windows authentication for your site in iis.

1)open iis.

2)select your site.

3)click on the authentication feature from the middle pane.

[image]

4)make sure windows authentication is enabled and rest of the are disabled.

[image]

to set authorization:

```
<system.webServer>
        <security>
            <authentication>
                <anonymousAuthentication enabled="false" />
                <windowsAuthentication enabled="true" />              
            </authentication>

           <authorization>
                <remove users="*" roles="" verbs="" />
                <add accessType="Deny" users="?" />
                <add accessType="Allow" roles="domainname\role" />
            </authorization>
        </security>
 </system.webServer>
```

deny = * means deny everyone

deny = ? means deny unauthenticated users

For more detail you could refer this below link:

[How to implement Windows authentication and authorization in ASP.NET](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/323176/how-to-implement-windows-authentication-and-authorization-in-asp-net)